# TypeError: Cannot read property 'code' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, react-component

**Dashboard.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const Dashboard = () => {
    return (
        <!--  Card Section  -->
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col s12 m6 l3">
                <div className="card blue-grey darken-1">
                    <div className="card-content white-text">
                        <span className="card-title center">20</span>
                        <p className="center">Task of Today</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="col s12 m6 l3">
                <div className="card blue-grey darken-1">
                    <div className="card-content white-text">
                        <span className="card-title center">20</span>
                        <p className="center">Bugs</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="col s12 m6 l3">
                <div className="card blue-grey darken-1">
                    <div className="card-content white-text">
                        <span className="card-title center">20</span>
                        <p className="center">Finished Task</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="col s12 m6 l3">
                <div className="card blue-grey darken-1">
                    <div className="card-content white-text">
                        <span className="card-title center">20</span>
                        <p className="center">Remaining Task</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Dashboard;
```

After importing this from app.js getting this error

```
./src/components/Dashboard/Dashboard.js
TypeError: Cannot read property 'code' of undefined
    at parser.next (<anonymous>)
    at normalizeFile.next (<anonymous>)
    at run.next (<anonymous>)
    at transform.next (<anonymous>)
```

I have no idea what is happening. There are no variable code. From where it comes?
Application working fine if i do not import Dashboard. Error occurring when i import Dashboard.js in app.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to remove the comment `<!--  Card Section  -->` in the component and it should work.

Correction:

```
import React from 'react';

const Dashboard = () => {
    return (
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col s12 m6 l3">
                <div className="card blue-grey darken-1">
                    <div className="card-content white-text">
                        <span className="card-title center">20</span>
                        <p className="center">Task of Today</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="col s12 m6 l3">
                <div className="card blue-grey darken-1">
                    <div className="card-content white-text">
                        <span className="card-title center">20</span>
                        <p className="center">Bugs</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="col s12 m6 l3">
                <div className="card blue-grey darken-1">
                    <div className="card-content white-text">
                        <span className="card-title center">20</span>
                        <p className="center">Finished Task</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="col s12 m6 l3">
                <div className="card blue-grey darken-1">
                    <div className="card-content white-text">
                        <span className="card-title center">20</span>
                        <p className="center">Remaining Task</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Dashboard;
```